# Modify Logging levels in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

In Python, we get both DEBUG and INFO messages when the level is set to DEBUG. And, we do not get DEBUG messages when level is set to INFO.

I want the exact opposite of this. I want only DEBUG messages when level is set to DEBUG. And both INFO and DEBUG messages when level is set to INFO.

All logs should be there in the console.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: If you are not constrained by an existing codebase, you could switch your use of DEBUG and INFO.

Comment: @JoshuaFox  Switching is not an option.

Comment: this is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): why do you need this? it doesn't make sense, what is your original problem?

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom `Handler`.

In the `emit` function, note `record.levelname` and print or don't print the record accordingly.

```
   import logging
   class MyHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
     def emit(self, record):     
       if record.levelname=="DEBUG":
         self.stream.write(msg)
         self.stream.write(self.terminator)
         self.flush()
```

Then use it in [the usual way](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html):

```
logger = logging.getLogger('spam_application')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = MyHandler() 
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Comment: How is this used?

Comment: attach MyHandler as  your  handler https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Answer (score 0):

This would log info logs to file and debug logs to console.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.Info)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this') 
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

Comment: I cannot use a file. All logs should be in the console.